# <!DOCTYPE> w3c validation error

Tags: w3c, w3c-validation

**delimiter ">" invalid: only name, "#IMPLIED" and parameter separators are allowed**

here is the validation link [w3c validation error](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.dbatechnologies.net/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.3%20http://validator.w3.org/services)

Hi All as per below answers i have updated some things but the problem is remain same

same code i have copied in to other link and i made only one change that is as you said `<!DOCTYPE >` modified as  `<!DOCTYPE html>`. my errors are increased to 446. [link-1](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.dbatechnologies.net/index.php&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.3%20http://validator.w3.org/services) with `<!DOCTYPE>`

and [link-2](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.dbatechnologies.net/index_1.php&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.3%20http://validator.w3.org/services) with `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 1):

Your `DOCTYPE` declaration is incorrect. It is

```
<!DOCTYPE >
```

When it should probably be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Not working here is the [link] [1] http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dbatechnologies.net%2Findex_1.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 [1]

Comment: That's a different link. The small amount of patience I had is now gone. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration, it's wrong.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp